# Django register form not showing up on admin users when submitted

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin, django-authentication

I want to create a register and login but when I create account in http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/ it doesn't show in admin (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/)

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', context)

def login(request):
    context = { }
    return render(request, 'user/login.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [

 path('register/', views.register, name = "register"),
 path('login/', views.login, name="login"),

]
```

user/register.html

```
<form method="POST" action=" ">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

    <input type="submit" name="Create User">
</form>
```

I need help, Thank you!

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">`.

Comment: hello Sir Willem! its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet...

## form.py

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']

        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            # 'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            # 'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

## view.py

```
def RegisterView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CutomerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            usrname= form.cleaned_data['username']
            print(usrname)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,f'{usrname} Successfully Registred')
            form = CutomerRegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CutomerRegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```